# Problem in viewing html file

Tags: visualforce, html, iframe

We are trying to show the html file in an iframe. Lets say the file Name is "Resume HTML" and content Type of is "htm". It was working fine, but for the past 2 weeks, it downloading the file instead of appearing in the iframe.

```
<apex:iframe src="/apex/OriginalResume?Id={!contactId}&where=cvPopup" height="1225px" scrolling="true"/>

public with sharing class OriginalResumeController {
public string pdfCVId {get; set;}
public string origCVId {get; set;}
public string htmlCVId {get; set;}
public string fileName {get; set;}
public DateTime uploadDate {get;set;}
public Boolean resumeAvailable {get;set;}
public string baseURL {get;set;}
public OriginalResumeController() { 
    String conId = apexpages.currentpage().getparameters().get('id');
    baseURL = System.URL.getSalesforceBaseUrl().getHost().remove('-api' );
    for(Sovren_Resume__c cv : [SELECT Id, (SELECT Name, ContentType, CreatedDate FROM Attachments) FROM Sovren_Resume__c WHERE contact__c = :conId Limit 1]) {
        for(Attachment att : cv.Attachments) {
            if(att.Name.endsWith('.pdf') || att.Name.endsWith('.doc') || att.Name.endsWith('.docx') || att.Name.endsWith('.txt') || Test.isRunningTest()) {
                origCVId = att.id;
            }
            //-- To Do Check if it will work in production
            if(String.isNotBlank(att.ContentType) && att.ContentType.contains('/pdf') || Test.isRunningTest()) {
                pdfCVId = att.Id;
                uploadDate = att.CreatedDate;
                fileName = att.Name;
            }
            else if(String.isNotBlank(att.ContentType) && (att.ContentType.contains('/html') || att.ContentType.contains('/htm') || att.ContentType.contains('htm') || att.ContentType.contains('html') || Test.isRunningTest())) {
                htmlCVId = att.Id;
                uploadDate = att.CreatedDate;
                fileName = att.Name;
            }
        }
    }

    System.debug(pdfCVid);
    System.debug(htmlCVId);
    if(pdfCVId == null && htmlCVId == null)
    {
        resumeAvailable = false;
    }
    else
    {
        resumeAvailable = true;
    }
    System.debug(resumeAvailable);
 }
}
```

We didn't change anything in our code. I tried with File Upload and Download security. I also tried setting as "Hybrid" but still it is downloading. Need help on this.

Comment: Can you provide the controller code for `OriginalResume` ?

Comment: I feel issue with your browser setting.

Comment: @karthikselva added in the question itself